# Parsing JSON [Node.JS]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I'm writing a bot in Node.JS and my commands are held in a JSON table kind of like this:

```
Commands = {
  "exit": {
    name: "exit",
    desc: "exits the bot",
    usage: "n/a",
    func: function() {
        process.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

and I want to know how I would loop through the Commands table to get thigs like the function/name of the command so I can actually check to see if the command was spoken etc.

Comment: is the command object is an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the command object using for in.

```
for (cmd in Commands) {
    //Code to deal with each of the command should go here.
    //cmd contains each of your commands.
    //cmd.name, cmd.usage, cmd.func gives each of the property name
    ....
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just started Node.JS but, how would I access cmd.name etc outside of the for loop?

Comment: if you look for any specific command, then you can assign that to some variable and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
  Commands.exit.name
```

If Commands  object is an array your could loop it.I made a simple jsfiddle

plz check
https://jsfiddle.net/tLLawaxh/

Answer (score 0):

if you have

```
var Commands = {
  'exit': {
    name: 'exit',
    desc: 'exits the bot',
    usage: 'n/a',
    func: function() {
      process.exit(0);
    }
  }
};
```

then something like

```
var key = "exit";
var name   = Commands[key].name;   <- this should be exit
var result = Commands[key].func(); <- this calls the func
```

with more error check

```
var ref  = Commands[key];
var name   = ref != null ? ref.name : undefined;
var result = ref != null ? ref.func() : undefined;
```